# How to print the data that have largest length using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I have this input:

```
1 happy,t,c,d
2 t,c
3 e,fgh,k
4 yk,j,f
5 leti,j,f,g
```

I want to print the length of the largest item (with comma as a delimiter), which should yield:

```
 1 5,1,1,1
 2 1,1
 3 1,3,1
 4 2,1,1
 5 4,1,1,1
```

And then I want to select the max value for the 2nd column finally creating:

```
 1 5
 2 1
 3 3
 4 2
 5 4
```

How can I do this in `awk`?

## 1) For the first task I have tried:

```
awk -v col=$2 -F',' '{OFS=","; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print length($i);}' test.data.txt
```

Which doesn't output correct data:

```
7
1
1
1
3
1
3
3
1
4
1
1
6
1
1
1
```

The only problem is that I am not able to use `-v` option properly to read only that column. So, I have all data in one column, and values added (from length) from column1 and space between column1 and column2.

## 2) To select the max value, I am doing:

```
awk -F',' '{OFS="\t"; m=length($1); for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (length($i) > m) m=length($i); print m}' test.data.txt
```

This works properly, but due to the presence of 1st column the values are added to the max values giving me:

```
7
3
3
4
6
```

instead of:

```
5
1
3
2
4
```

Lastly, I want to merge these two processes in one go. Any suggestions on improvements?

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F'[, ]' -v OFS="," '{m=length($2);for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) if (length($i) > m) m=length($i)}{print $1,m}' file
1,5
2,1
3,3
4,2
5,4
```

For the first case:

```
awk -F'[, ]' -v OFS="," '{printf "%s",$1;for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",(i==2?" ":OFS),length($i)}{print ""}'
1 5,1,1,1
2 1,1
3 1,3,1
4 2,1,1
5 4,1,1,1
```

Shorter alternative:

```
awk -F'[, ]' -v OFS="," '{printf "%s ",$1;for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",length($i),(i==NF?ORS:OFS)}'
```

While `print` in awk prints data and changes line by printing a new line at the end, `printf` does not change line on it's own.

PS: Thanks Ed Morton for the valuable comment.

Answer (score 3):

We start with this data file:

```
$ cat data
1 happy,t,c,d
2 t,c
3 e,fgh,k
4 yk,j,f
5 leti,j,f,g
```

For the first task:

```
$ awk '{n=split($2,a,/,/); printf "%2s %s",$1,length(a[1]); for(i=2; i<=n; i++) printf ",%s",length(a[i]); print""}' data
 1 5,1,1,1
 2 1,1
 3 1,3,1
 4 2,1,1
 5 4,1,1,1
```

For the second task:

```
$ awk '{n=split($2,a,/,/); max=length(a[1]); for(i=2; i<=n; i++) if (length(a[i])>max)max=length(a[i]); print $1,max}' data
1 5
2 1
3 3
4 2
5 4
```

#### How it works

For the second task:

- `n=split($2,a,/,/)`

  We split up the contents of field 2 into array `a`
- `max=length(a[1])`

  We assign the length of the first element of array `a` to the awk variable `max`.
- `for(i=2; i<=n; i++) if (length(a[i])>max)max=length(a[i])`

  If any succeeding element of array `a` is larger than `max`, we update `max.
- `print $1,max`

  We print the first field and the value of `max`.

Comment: `max=length(a[i])` :)

Comment: @PesaThe Oops!  Thank you.  Answer updated with `i` for `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to golf this down:

```
gawk -F'[ ,]' '{m=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){l=length($i);if(l>m)m=l}print$1,m}'

perl -MList::Util=max -F'\s+|,' -lne'$,=" ";print shift(@F),max map{length}@F'
perl -MList::Util=max -F'\s+|,' -lne'print"@{[shift(@F),max map{length}@F]}"'
perl -MList::Util=max -F'\s+|,' -lpe'$_="@{[shift(@F),max map{length}@F]}"'    

ruby -F'[ ,]' -lape'$_="#{$F[0]} #{$F[1..-1].map{|e|e.size}.max}"'
```

Comment: nothing gawk-specific about that awk answer, it'll work in any awk, and you shouldn't use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Comment: Well it's golf so obfuscated goes with the territory. I had thought that not all awks support a regex in FS

Comment: Only old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris) doesn't support a regexp in FS but it also doesn't support many other things, is generally broken, and must never be used so it's not worth saying "... except old, broken awk" on every script, just assume no-ones using that. See http://awk.freeshell.org/oawk for some its issues.

Comment: btw fore! `awk -F'[ ,]' '{m=0;while(NF-->2){l=length($NF);if(l>m)m=l}print$1,m}' file`. Caveat - that will work in any awk I know of BUT the effect of decrementing NF is technically undefined behavior per POSIX. That's more of an issue when people are relying on `NF--` to delete the final field of the record as then YMMV depending on which awk you're using but that isn't the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume I have following file:

```sql
abc             14            10     lsjhmehrofer
adlcwd          23            124    cerklfelkfv
sjxhkj          34            868    tguyjggt 
vergrtbhretshrt 23            24335  gdrvhtyfjrbhvdgthter
```

you can use:
`awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn | head -1 " }' abc.txt`

```js
priyankauser ~ % awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn | head -2 " }' abc.txt
57 4 vergrtbhretshrt 23            24335  gdrvhtyfjrbhvdgthter
49 1 abc             14            10     lsjhmehrofer
priyankauser ~ % awk '{ print length(), NR, $0 | "sort -rn | head -1 " }' abc.txt
57 4 vergrtbhretshrt 23            24335  gdrvhtyfjrbhvdgthter
```

here 4 is the line number that has max length

`57` ***4*** `vergrtbhretshrt 23            24335  gdrvhtyfjrbhvdgthter`